# How to expose decorator attributes in Grape Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-entity

I'm working on exposing some data to a mobile client through the API. Some of that data is defined in a decorator.

`app/decorators/customer_opportunity_decorator.rb`

```
  def potential_savings
    return 'N/A' if opportunity.nil?

    multiplier = Customer.get_multiplier(...)
 
    return 'N/A' if multiplier.blank?

    ...more logic
  end
```

We're using Grape Entities in our API layer and I'm not sure about how to pass this logic through the API. It doesn't seem like it should live in a decorator if being exposed as an API field.

```
module Entities
    class Opportunity < BaseEntity
        expose :id
        expose :name
        expose :potential_savings # need this field on the API

...
```

And then there's an api model `ApiOpportunity`

```
class ApiOpportunity
  attr_reader :id, :name, :potential_savings

  def initialize(opportunity)
    @id = opportunity.id
    @name = opportunity.name
    @potential_savings = opportunity.potential_savings # this approach doesn't seem to work
  end
end
```

Is this logic that I should move elsewhere? Is it fine to remain as a decorator and somehow pass through in the API?

Comment: Are you passing the decorator through Grape? If so then this is fine. If not you will need to move this to the model. Just need a bit more context on how you are rending the object in the grape api

Comment: @engineersmnky have added info to the post, but I attempted to pass this info through an api model. It doesn't work as expected.

Comment: For that to work `oppurtunity` in `ApiDesiredPlacement#new`  needs to be a `CustomerOppurtunityDecorator` object. Otherwise you can move this logic to the model. Not sure why you need the `ApiDesiredPlacement` object I would just use your decorator for both